# More comfortable way renaming a Class in Eclipse using CDT for C++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm wondering if there's an easier way using CDT for this refactoring task. Not only a simple renaming, also  a rename of header and source files, correcting all `#include` statements, rename member-attributes in other classes and so on.

Don't know if it's possible or if one has to fumble around in all project files, or is there an extern tool which is useful for this purpose?

Comment: This site lead me to ask this question, because it looks a little outdated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Alt+Shift+R does everything except it doesn't change the filenames of .cpp and .h files.
Everything else is done by this operation.